# Inconsistent Intent Classification and Score Prediction in 2 LUIS models with same utterances

Tags: azure, neural-network, deep-learning, azure-language-understanding

We are trying to move LUIS model from  Dev to Testing environment. But we are facing a challenge where in after moving the LUIS model, the confidence produced by LUIS for each intent, for a given utterance is different in both the models. That is, the Dev and Testing LUIS model don’t produce same confidence score for a given utterance.

We have tried below 3 ways to move LUIS model but LUIS models produced from each process is not consistent with the original one.
1. Cloning a LUIS App
2. Importing/Exporting a LUIS App
3.Uploading utterances manually to a LUIS App

Requesting your advice on how to solve this inconsistent confidence score problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changed scores may be attributed to the changes you make in your models and features. Also, LUIS is [non-deterministic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-utterance#training-utterances) so you cannot guarantee to get the exact same score after a retrain or cloning the app.  
Also I'd suggest to use staging slot to [publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/publishapp) for testing the app. Hope this helps!!